# Improving performance calculating Kernel Matrix

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd

def tanimotoKernel(xs, ys):
    a = 0
    b = 0
    for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
        a += min(x, y)
        b += max(x, y)
    return a / b

#gammaExp = 1/(np.exp(gamma) - 1), calculated outside the kernel
def tanimotoLambdaKernel(xs,ys, gamma, gammaExp):
    return np.exp(gamma * tanimotoKernel(xs,ys) - 1) * gammaExp

class GramBuilder:
    def __init__(self, Kernel):
        self._Kernel = Kernel
    def generateMatrixBuilder(self, X1, X2):
        gram_matrix = np.zeros((X1.shape[0], X2.shape[0]))
        for i, x1 in enumerate(X1):
            for j, x2 in enumerate(X2):
                gram_matrix[i, j] = self._Kernel(x1, x2)
        return gram_matrix

gammaList = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
CList = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]


X, y = datasets.load_digits(return_X_y=True)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

svc_list = [
    (svm.SVC(
        kernel=GramBuilder(
            partial(tanimotoLambdaKernel, gamma = x, gammaExp = 1/(np.exp(x) - 1)))
        .generateMatrixBuilder), 
     x)
    for x in gammaList
]

gammas   = []
Cs       = []
accuracy = []
for svc, gamma in svc_list:
    print("Training gamma ", gamma)
    clf = GridSearchCV(svc, {'C' : CList}, verbose = 1, n_jobs = -1)
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    gammas.append(gamma)
    Cs.append(clf.best_params_['C'])
    accuracy.append(clf.best_score_)
```

For this toy dataset, I have to wait 50 minutes approx to perform all the cross validations in the loop.

The first improvement I did was to calculate `gammaExp` outside the function, so I can save millions of exponentials. Also I multiplication is faster than division, so I calculated the inverse of the exponential minus one to also try to save more time.

With those modifications I improved a lot the time training the models, however I need it to be faster, so I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Code optimization questions are actually off-topic here, please post to Code Review instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Numpy to speed up the min/max operations. Then you can use Numba's JIT to speed up the code even more by inlining calls.

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def tanimotoKernel(xs, ys):
    a = np.minimum(xs, ys).sum()
    b = np.maximum(xs, ys).sum()
    return a / b

@nb.njit
def tanimotoLambdaKernel(xs,ys, gamma, gammaExp):
    return np.exp(gamma * tanimotoKernel(xs,ys) - 1) * gammaExp

# [...]
```

The above code should be correct and is more than **20 times faster** on my machine. It took actually only few minutes to complete.

I think you can speed things up even more by removing the partial call and use Numba for the `GramBuilder` class too (look at the Numba documentation to JIT class, partial function are probably not supported, but you can store values in the class and do part of the job yourself). Moreover, note that many operation seems performed multiple times in the kernel. I is probably possible to compute them once (the kernel is called with the same x2 multiple times and recompute the max again and again).

Comment: Thanks! Really a game changer. I had a look and maybe we can also get some improvement when building the matrix, because `gram_matrix[i, j]`== `gram_matrix[j, i]`. However I'm doing something wrong, because I get some errors, maybe because the shapes of `X1` and `X2` can be different.

Comment: You get some error with the provided code or with your optimization regarding the `gram_matrix` symmetry? For the `gram_matrix`, it is weird to have a symmetry with different shapes. What would it means practically? Anyway, to simplify the optimisation in the first place, you can split this code in two parts: an optimized case where the shape are the same and an old unoptimized case where they are different.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't have to calculate `g[j,j]` because I can copy `g[i,j]` directly, avoiding the extra calculations.